# Error TS2339: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Response'

Tags: angular, rxjs

What am I doing wrong here?

I get this error:

> TS2339: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Response'.

What I have searched for is that I cannot use find when I want to find a movie by title and not id?

What I'm doing right now is I want to be able to click on a movie title and then get onto another component/side where I can show information about the movie/pictures so on.

**Code from movie.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/operator/filter';

import { Movie } from './shared/Movie';

interface IMovieData {results : Movie;}
export interface IVideoData {results : IVideo[];}
export interface IVideo {'id': string; 'key':string; 'name':string; 'site': 
string; 'type':string; }

@Injectable()
export class MovieService {

private movie : any;
private key : string;

constructor(private http : Http) { }

getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]> {
return this.http.get('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?
primary_release_date.gte=2014-09-15&primary_release_date.lte=2014-10-
22&api_key=mykey')
  .map((res: Response) => res.json()['results']);
}

public getMovie(title: string): Observable<Movie> {
return this.http.get("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=" + 
title + "&api_key=mykey")
  .map(movies => movies.find(movie => movie.title == title));
}
```

**code from moviedetail.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import  'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Movie } from '../Shared/Movie';
import { MovieService } from '../movie.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-moviedetail',
templateUrl: './moviedetail.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./moviedetail.component.css']
})
export class MoviedetailComponent implements OnInit {

public movie : Movie;

constructor(
private http: Http,
private movieService : MovieService, 
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private router: Router
          )
{
}

ngOnInit() {


 this.movieService.getMovie(this.route.snapshot.params['title']).subscribe(success=>{this.movie=success;});
} 




public gotoMovies(){
this.router.navigate(['/movielist']);
}

}
```

Comment: The message is extremely clear. You're trying to call find() on an object (movies) that is of type Response, and there is no such method in Response. What you receive from a Http call is a Response, not an array of movies. What's even more surprising is that you seem to somehow know it, since the first HTTP call does use the response correctly. Side note: please, take a minimum of care to indent your code properly before posting it.

Comment: Ive used some time to search for an answer on the internet before i posted, thats why i might know that i cant use find on a response. 

but that dosent change i still dont know how to solve my problem and not to be rude but ur answer didnt really help. i cant see what i should use or how

Comment: Look at the first HTTP call. It does; `.map((res: Response) => res.json()['results'])`. Because what you get is a Response, that you need to parse as JSON. Look at the second one: `.map(movies => movies.find(...))`. That makes no sense. Just as for the first HTTP call, what you'll get is a Response, not an array of movies. So you need, just as for the first call, to get the json body out of the response.

Comment: i appreciate your answers, and i think i know what you mean about it but i still cant see how i shall make it, worked all day long with this and im pretty new so i give up now. :D

Comment: public getMovie(title: string): Observable<Movie> {
    return this.http.get("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie? 
    query=" + title + "&api_key=mykey")
      .map((res: Response) => res.json(),{movie : this.movie.title == title});

      }

Comment: is it like this you mean? i tryed it but it didnt work.